# Decide if the first argument's list contains elements in the second argument's list

Tags: haskell, recursion

> Define the
>
> `listCheck :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]] -> Bool`
>
> function that decides whether the first argument's list of words contains a word that is also in the second argument's list. We can assume that both lists only contain lowercase letters. If at least one of the arguments is an empty list, then return `False`.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> listCheck ["hey", "hello", "hi"] ["whatsup", "hi"] == True
> ```
>
> ```
> listCheck ["hey", "hello", "hi"] ["whatsup"] == False
> ```

So far, I've tried:

```
listCheck [] _ = False
listCheck _ [] = False    
listCheck (x:xs) [y]
  | x == y = True
  | otherwise = listCheck (xs) [y]
```

Which does what I expected. It only checks for the first element of the second argument (it always returns the correct value if the second list has only one element, so at least I got that right). I don't know how to implement the recursion for the rest of the second lists' elements.

Comment: these are not parameters, but arguments. parameters are variables, arguments are values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```hs
listCheck :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]] -> Bool
listCheck [] _ = False
listCheck (x:xs) ys = go x ys || listCheck xs ys where
   go _ [] = False
   go x (y:ys)
     | x == y = True
     | otherwise = go x ys
```

We use a helper function `go` to compare one element from one list with all the elements from the other list. If an element `x` is not found in the list `ys`, we try the rest of `xs` on `ys`. `||` guarantees that the function returns as soon as a match is found without checking the rest. Finally, if `xs` is exhausted we can be sure that there is no match and return `False`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! One more question: In this context, does `||` mean `or` or is it like a `break` statement in C++?

Comment: `||` is a logical or that executes the RHS only if the LHS evaluates to False (like a short circuit). If the LHS evaluates to True, it just returns True without considering the RHS. Also, AFAIK, `||` is also a short circuiting logical or in C++.

Comment: I see, thank you for you help.

Comment: You can use the same `||` trick in `go`; `go x (y:ys) = x == y || go x ys`.You can alternatively use existing functions; ```listCheck xs ys = any (`elem` ys) xs```. For efficiency, use a `Set`, as in ```listCheck xs ys = any (`S.member` S.fromList ys) xs```.

Comment: @DanielWagner that's an answer. :)